# How to evaluate a promise in an if statement

Tags: angular, ionic4

Im trying to get the value of a promise in the evaluation part of an if statement.
My code:

```
if (this.storage.get("lang")) {
  this.storage.get("lang").then(lang => {
    this.translate.use(lang);
  });
```

The purpose is to check if 'lang' is already set, and get 'lang' if it is. The `storage.get()` method is from @ionic/storage. if i just log `this.storage.get('lang')` i get this JSON:

```
Object { __zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: [] }
```

and if i run the code, i get the error:
​

```
error: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot GET /assets/i18n/null.json</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n"
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: lazyInit()
 }
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8100/assets/i18n/null.json: 404 Not Found"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
url: "http://localhost:8100/assets/i18n/null.json"
<prototype>: Object { constructor: HttpErrorResponse()
 }
```

So im assuming the issue is that although `storage.get('lang')` is returning `__zone_symbol__value: null`, the Object returned by `storage.get('lang')` isnt a null object, so my `if(storage.get('lang'))` evaluates to true.

has anybody ever worked with the @ionic/storage module and encountered this issue, or does anybody have a solution? Thanks!

Comment: Did any of these answers fixed your issue? If yes, please consider marking one of them as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll hazard an answer, although I don't have the ability to test code at this time.

It seems the flow you're looking for is:

```
When this promise,
Produces a value,
Do Something if it isn't null.
```

To do that, your flow would have to be:

```
Get The Promise,
"Then" to get the Value,
Check The Value,
Do Something if it isn't null.
```

So you sort of need to turn your logic inside out.

Instead of:

```
If Promise // there will always be one!
Get Value,
And Do Something if it isn't null
```

You'd have to go:

```
Get Promise,
"Then" for Value (whatever it might be),
(Inside the Then block) If there is one, Do Something.
```

So you don't "if" at the top level. You just get the promise, "then" it, and inside the then block, check the value and do your thing.

A lot of people run into this with promises and observables. "How do I check the value, if the value isn't available at the top level?" Answer: you don't. You just run the subscription or "then", and inside that block, check and run your condition.

So a quick stab at some maybe-it-runs code:

```
this.storage.get("lang").then(lang => {
    if ( lang ) { 
       this.translate.use(lang);
     }
  });
```

Comment: Glad to help, you could mark the answer as accepted to help out other folks with the thinking.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use promises like that.

```
if (somePromise)
```

Will always evaluate to true, since it will return a promise, not the resolved value.

You have to get the resolved value with

```
somePromise.then(value => {
    if (value) {
        // use value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your current implementation.

1. You're calling `this.storage.get` multiple times which is redundant.
2. `this.storage.get` returns a Promise but what you're looking for in the `if` condition is the resolved value of the `promise`.

You could use the `async` `await` syntax instead of `.then` syntax to make the code more readable while resolving the issue:

```
async yourFunction() {
  const lang = await this.storage.get("lang")
  if (lang) this.translate.use(lang); 
}
```

Make sure to define this code in an `async` function as I've done or else it will throw an error.